# When creating a reference variable, what are we exactly doing?

Tags: java, class, variables, types, constructor

Noob here, with some questions about fundamental things in Java.

If we have a class `Person` with a constructor (also Person) we can create a reference variable like this:

```
Person johnny = new Person();
```

Let's say we have just created in a class `People` an object, `johnny`.
It holds an "address" to where the object and its values are kept, unlike objects of primitives types do (e.g. int x = 5; has the value 5, `johnny` is a "link" to the value - if I've understood things correctly.)

**1st word:** `Person` is a class/type (<-- edited here), but:

- What does a class/type do? What does it entail? Perhaps: what does a type do, if it is not a 'primitive type'?

**2nd word:** `johnny` is a reference variable, of type Person.
- If I am missing something, please enlighten me :)

**3rd word:** `new` this just states that we are creating the new object.

**4th word:** second `Person`:

- This is the object we are creating?
- Is this the constructor or the class we are referring to?

ALSO:

- The value (address) that the variable is referring to is everything after the equal sign? Is the address `new Person`?

LASTLY: Polymorphism. 
So if we have a sub-class `Adult`, which extends the super-class `Person`, then we can do this:

```
Person amanda = new Adult();
```

- What are we doing now?
- Is `amanda` of class type Person and refers to an object in the class `Adult`?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You can only have a reference to an Object, so the type of the reference is the upper limit in the hierarchy of the class it can be.

Comment: read a decent textbook on basic OO principles

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> 1st word: 'Person' is a class type

Yes, but it might just as well be a primitive type, does not matter for that "first word" which is the type declaration for the variable.

Another example would be

```
 int a = 1;
```

When you declare a variable or parameter in Java, the name is preceded by the type.

> 2nd word: 'johnny' is a reference variable, of type Person

That's right. You name your variable `johnny` here. And its type is what you specified for it right in front of the name.

> 3rd word: 'new' this just states that we are creating the new object.

`new` means that we are calling a constructor (of the class that is following the `new`). That is indeed how you create objects in Java.

> 4th word: second 'Person

That is the name of the class that you are calling the constructor of. This will always return a new instance of exactly that class (not of a subclass). There can be more than one constructor to choose from for a given class, they are differentiated by parameter counts and types (in your case, a constructor without any parameters).

> The value (address) that the variable is referring to is everything after the equal sign? The address is 'new Person'?

`new Person()` returns a reference to the newly created object instance. It will be stored in your variable `johnny`.

> LASTLY: Polymorphism.

Your `Adult` class is a subclass of `Person`. This means that you can use it in all situations where a `Person` would be required. In particular, you can assign it to a `Person`-type variable (such as `johnny`) and call all `Person` methods on it.

Comment: This was helpful. I needed to have concrete answers for this exact instance.

Comment: About Polym.: I now understand that the variable is referencing an object (or should I say instance here?) in `adult`. But, I need clarification about what the class ("type") `Person` does? I thought it set the type of the variable (_how a variable can be set to a type, which is actually a class or how a class can be used as a type is confusing_).

Comment: Every variable or other piece of data in Java has a type. There are two kind of types: primitive types (like `int`) or Object types. The latter are organized in a class hierarchy and this is user-extensible. Every `class` you write defines a new type (which will be a subtype of some other class, with `java.lang.Object` as the base type for all classes).

Answer (score -1):

This is all too confused for words.

> When creating a reference type, what are we exactly doing?

Nothing. There is no such operation in Java.

> When we have a class (or super-class, I'll get back to that) Person with a constructor (also Person) we can create a reference type like this:

No you can't. What you are creating here is a *reference.* You are *not* creating a type, let alone a 'reference type'.

```
Person johnny = new Person();
```

> We have just created in a new class People (e.g.) an object, johnny.

I see no evidence of a class `People`, but I'll take your word for it.

> It holds an "address" to where the object and its values are kept, unlike objects of primitives types do (e.g. int x = 5; has the value 5, johnny is a "link" to the value - if I've understood things correctly.)

Correct.

```
1st word: 'Person' is a class type, but:
```

No it isn't. `Person` is a class. Period.

> What does a class type do? What does it entail?

Nothing because it doesn't exist. A *class* on the other hand is a kind of template for constructing objects from, that determines its data members and what code can be called on it.

> Perhaps: what does a type do, if it is not a 'primitive type'?

It extends the type system beyond the primitive types, in a way which can be reasoned about and computed, via inheritance, interface implementation, and the Liskov substituion principle (q.v.).

> 2nd word: 'johnny' is a reference variable, of type Person. - If I am missing something, please enlighten me :)

Correct.

> 3rd word: 'new' this just states that we are creating the new object.

Correct.

4th word: second `Person`: This is the object we are creating?

This is the *class* (or 'type' if you insist) of the object we are creating.

> Is this the constructor or the class we are referring to?

Both. The arguments or lack of them determine which constructor is called. The name of the constructor is the same as the name of the class, by the rules of Java.

> The value (address) that the variable is referring to is everything after the equal sign? The address is 'new Person'?

The variable refers to the *object* that was created. There is no concept of 'address' in Java.

> LASTLY: Polymorphism. So if we have a sub-classes 'Adult', which extends the super-class 'Person', then we can do this:

```
Person amanda = new Adult();
```

> What are we doing now?

You are creating an object of type `Adult` and referring to it via a reference of type `Person`, which can only succeed if `Person` is a base class of or an interface implemented by `Adult`.

> Is 'amanda' of class type Person

'amanda' is a reference of type/class `Person`.

> and an object in the class 'Adult'?

`amanda` isn't an object at all. The *object it refers to* is an object of class `Adult`.

Comment: Oh, thanks: I accidentally wrote reference type instead of reference variable. I've corrected it.

Comment: I was also too fast with `amanda` - as I previously mentioned the reference variable isn't an object. Also corrected.

Comment: About polymorphism: I understand now that the reference variable refers to an object created in the class stated after `new`, but could you clarify what the class ("type") `Person` does than? I thought it set the type of the variable (_how a variable can be set to a type, which is actually a class or how a class can be used as a type is confusing_)

Comment: You're using 'type' and 'class' as though there were two different things. They aren't. There are two 'types' of type in Java: primitive types and class types.